# git svn rebase always conflicts with my own commits

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm using git svn to work with a client who has an svn repository (our stuff is in github).

So I follow the instructions and do a git svn rebase and then git svn dcommit

That worked the very first time, but ever since then rebasing always conflicts on almost every commit. It seems like it doesn't realize which commits are mine, and complains that things are conflicting. Every time I have to git rebase --skip my way through until it passes those and successfully applies my latest commits. It never figures out where I was the last time I did a rebase (which I believe is what is supposed to happen).

First of all... why? Then can I get around this somehow?

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Deleting their old build management stuff as its pretty crappy. Will re-build at some point.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
Applying: Added some error checking around Android specific calls
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:16: space before tab in indent.
            Android.hideKeyboard();
<stdin>:31: space before tab in indent.
                    Android.launchNewAccount();
warning: 2 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/LoginForm.js deleted in HEAD and modified in Added some error checking around Android specific calls. Version Added some error checking around Android specific calls of src/LoginForm.js left in tree.
Auto-merging src/ChildPanel.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/ChildPanel.js
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 Added some error checking around Android specific calls

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how you got yourself into this situation, but I can tell you how to get yourself out.

First, create a new branch based on the upstream SVN: `git checkout -b mynewbranch refs/remotes/oldbranch` (use the git-svn ref ID here).

Then, check it out: `git checkout mynewbranch`.

Finally, cherry-pick the commits from your new branch **which were not committed to SVN** (something like `git cherry-pick refs/remotes/oldbranch..oldbranch`.

The most likely cause of the problems you're seeing is that you rewrote history after pushing a change to SVN; when you use `git-svn` to make a commit, it puts the `git-svn-id` *in the commit log*, which changes the revision hash. If you then move the commit around, you start working in an alternate universe where the SVN versions conflict with the non-SVN local ones.

Comment: I assume by git-svn ref ID you mean the branch name 'remotes/git-svn'?

Comment: Er... git co isn't a command. git checkout I assume? (Just making sure I'm not using git svn at that point)

Comment: Is git cherry-pick refs/remotes/oldbranch..oldbranch supposed to be git cherry-pick refs/remotes/oldbranch..master?

Comment: Beautiful. I only needed to pick one commit so I used the hash, still curious what that command was supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry to comment spam. Follow up question. Could pushing my changes to github first and then doing a git svn dcommit be what caused that problem? How could I still do that? (We work internally on github and then occasionally push to the client's svn).

Comment: @BobSpryn I have `git co` aliased to `git checkout`. Good catch. The cherry-pick command was correct: you want all the changes on the old branch but not on its SVN parent, in order. The problem with pushing your changes to github first is that the post-SVN-commit revisions are different, as I just said, so you can't ever pull back *from* github or push again... Make a separate branch to which you port the changes and `dcommit` them, but never do anything else on, if you must work for both destinations.